# Use dictionary instead of List - get ith entry

Tags: c#, dictionary, while-loop

Perhaps I am just having my dumb moment right now. I have the following:

```
List<DirectoryEntry> list = new List<DirectoryEntry>();
List.Add(startEntry);
int i=0;
while(i < list.Count) {
    DirectoryEntry entry = list[i];
    foreach(DirectoryEntry child in GetChildEntries(entry)) {
        if(!list.Contains(child)) // Do not add if entry already in list!
            list.Add(child);
    }
}
```

This does not work because Contains somehow returns false for two directoryEntries that point to the same AD object.

So I thought to make a Dictionary from that and store the distinguishedName along with the entry:

```
Dictionary<string,DirectoryEntry> list = new Dictionary<string,DirectoryEntry>();
List.Add(startEntry.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value,startEntry);
int i=0;
while(i < list.Count) {
    DirectoryEntry entry = list[i]; // Does not work, because the index is a string here.
                                    // How to get the ith entry from the dictionary?
    foreach(DirectoryEntry child in GetChildEntries(entry)) {
        var dn = child.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;
        if(!list.ContainsKey(dn)) list.Add(dn,child);
    }
}
```

The question, as stated in the code comment:

**How to get the ith entry from the dictionary?**

Comment: You don't. Dictionary/hash table has no inherent notion of *order* and is used for lookup by key. If you just want to store indexed key-value pairs (when index is really important), use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, DirectoryEntry>>`...

Comment: You can use an OrderedDictionary. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Use ElementAt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you need the check at all? You're walking down the children of an entry. Unless there's some sort of [loop](http://xkcd.com/981/) going on, you're never going to hit the same entry twice (assuming `GetChildEntries` does what it appears to).

Comment: @TimS You nailed it: Sometimes, there is a loop. Group A contains a Group B which contains Group A...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you *can* use `list.ElementAt(i)` to get the i<sup>th</sup> element in the order they *happen* to be returned by the dictionary - but there's no guarantee as to what order that is, or that it will stay consistent over time. I would strongly recommend *avoiding* thinking of a dictionary has having any concept of order.

It seems to me that you just need to iterate over the dictionary though:

```
foreach (var entry in list)
{
    ...
}
```

That leads to another problem though, which is that you're modifying the collection you're iterating over *while* you're iterating over it, which will fail. You might want to consider creating a *new* dictionary while you're iterating, and then add all the entries to the original one afterwards.

It's unclear whether you really want a dictionary or not though. We don't know what you're really trying to achieve - there are many different options here.

EDIT: If you want to flatten, you could do something like:

```
var entries = new Dictionary<string, DirectoryEntry>();
var queue = new Queue<DirectoryEntry>();
queue.Enqueue(startEntry);
while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    var candidate = queue.Dequeue();
    string key = candidate.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;
    if (!entries.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        entries[key] = candidate;
        foreach (var child in GetChildEntries(candidate))
        {
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}
```

You could "hide" the `foreach` loop by creating your own `EnqueueAll` extension method on `Queue<T>`, if you wanted.

This feels to me like simpler code to understand than iterating over a collection you're still adding to.

EDIT: And if you don't need to look up by distinguished name later, you can use a `HashSet<DirectoryEntry>` with a [custom equality comparer](http://pastebin.com/eijZCZt9):

```
var entries = new HashSet<DirectoryEntry>(new DirectoryEntryEqualityComparer());
var queue = new Queue<DirectoryEntry>();
queue.Enqueue(startEntry);
while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    if (entries.Add(candidate))
    {
        foreach (var child in GetChildEntries(candidate))
        {
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already decided against using `foreach` here, because it seems to bloat up the code and make it less understandable, since this would require nested loops.

Comment: @Alexander: I don't see what you mean - it looks *more* readable to me, if you're just trying to get every element. Accessing by integer index is simply a bad idea, IMO. If you could explain more about what you're trying to achieve, we may well be able to come up with a much simpler approach.

Comment: I am trying to flatten a graph of objects. Running over the list while adding items at the end of the same list means that breadth-first can be done neatly in a single loop. I can't do that with foreach.

Comment: @Alexander: I'd probably do that with a queue of entries to potentially add then - you can keep pulling the first one of those with `Dequeue`, then see whether or not you need to add the entry to the collection you're building up. Or if you *really* want to use your `List<T>`, you could just have a separate `HashSet<string>` for entries you've already seen.

Comment: @Alexander: I've added a queue-based solution to my answer.

Comment: I'd consider using a `HashSet<DirectoryEntry>` instead of a `Dictionary`. You can use [this `IEqualityComparer<>` that I wrote](http://pastebin.com/eijZCZt9).

Comment: @TimS.: I agree if Alexander doesn't need to look up by name. That'll simplify other bits, too. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are not ordered. You don't need a dictionary here. You just need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method in your class so that `Contains` method will know how do you wanna compare two `DictionaryEntry`.Or if you want to compare them based on a property you can use linq:

```
if(!list.Any(x => x.SomeProp == child.SomeProp)) 
        list.Add(child);
```

Comment: I want to compare two `DirectoryEntry`, which is a class that I didn't write. But yes, I could use the LINQ statement...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the ith entry from a dictionary. A dictionary is not a list nor an array, it is a dictionary. The items are stored in a hash (not neccessarily in order). Imagine if you took a list of items then removed all the links to the previous and next item, then hashing those items. That is kind've what a dictionary is.

Comment: OP is not asking what a dictionary is, or what its like.  I dont think this answers the question at all.

Comment: @paqogomez I believe that "You cannot get the ith entry from a dictionary." answers the question "How to get the ith entry from the dictionary?" quite perfectly - if it is true (it seems to be, given the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

list.Values.ElementAt(n)

(remember to be 'using System.Linq')